# Why wont conda work in my Azure Machine Learning startup script

Tags: bash, shell, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to develop a startup script for Azure Machine Learning compute instances and I am running into some strange issues when testing.

My code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
ENVIRONMENT=azureml_py38
conda --version
export HTTPS_PROXY=******
conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
conda create -n custom_env python=3.10 -y
conda activate custom_env
conda install -y pip
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name custom_env --display-name "(custom_env)"
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install azureml-core
echo "$PWD"
```

throws this error `/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/ld-custom-compute-v002/code/Users/ME/custom_compute_startup.sh: line 4: conda: command not found`
For all of the conda commands.

However if I have this as my code I do not get these errors but the working directory becomes /home/azureuser. I want these command to be run at a more distinct directory such as /home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/users/me

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo -u azureuser -i <<'EOF' #key change
ENVIRONMENT=azureml_py38
conda --version
export HTTPS_PROXY=******
conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
conda create -n custom_env python=3.10 -y
conda activate custom_env
conda install -y pip
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name custom_env --display-name "(custom_env)"
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install azureml-core
echo "$PWD"
EOF
```

Here is an online example that Azure themselves points to as a means to do something very similar. You will notice that the script does not use sudo -u azureuser -i until after it has run some commands. https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/setup/setup-ci/setup-custom-conda-env.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue with provided bash code.
[image]

It seems like the second script is working other than it's giving default working directory as `/home/azureuser`.

One possible solution is by sourcing the Conda initialization script to set up the necessary environment variables. This should ensure that the `conda` command is available in your script.
Here's the modified version of the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x
ENVIRONMENT=azureml_py38
export HTTPS_PROXY=******
source /anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh  # Load conda into the script's environment

conda --version
conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
conda create -n custom_env python=3.10 -y
conda activate custom_env
conda install -y pip
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name custom_env --display-name "(custom_env)"
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install azureml-core
echo "$PWD"
```

With this the current directory is changed to required path.
[image]

Another possible solution with second scripts is by changing the directory before executing any Conda command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo -u azureuser -i <<'EOF'
ENVIRONMENT=azureml_py38
conda --version
export HTTPS_PROXY=******
cd /home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/users/me
conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
conda create -n custom_env python=3.10 -y
conda activate custom_env
conda install -y pip
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name custom_env --display-name "(custom_env)"
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install azureml-core
echo "$PWD"
EOF
```

This way, you'll get the current working directory as per requirement.
[image]

Comment: Adding the conda source seems to have fixed it!